# Trigger a Transition Animation after adding it to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css-transitions

I'm trying to add an element to the DOM and then add a new class to trigger a transition animation.

```
// -- 1 -- Circle Already is in the DOM
// <div class="circle circle1 hwaccel"></div>
$('.circle1').addClass("dropped"); // Works!

// -- 2 -- Circle is added to the DOM with jQuery
var $c = $('<div class="circle circle2 hwaccel"></div>').appendTo( $('body') );
$c.addClass("dropped");
// Doesn't animate. Also tried $c.toggleClass("dropped");

// -- 3 -- Circle is added to the DOM with vanilla JS
var circleClass = "circle circle3 hwaccel";
var circleElt = document.createElement("div");
circleElt.setAttribute("class", circleClass);
document.body.appendChild( circleElt );
circleElt.setAttribute("class", circleClass + " dropped");
// Doesn't animate. :(
```

What am I doing wrong? fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/luken/DsLhJ/

Answer (score 1):

Someone will have to speak up with the proper terminology to explain why this is necessary, but I can explain what you need to do.

You can't add and apply the style in the same action. The browser needs a 'start' class and an 'end class' applied separately. The easiest fix is to wrap the addition of the class inside a setTimeout.

So change this:

```
var $c = $('<div class="circle circle2 hwaccel"></div>').appendTo( $('body') );
$c.addClass("dropped");
```

To this:

```
var $c = $('<div class="circle circle2 hwaccel"></div>').appendTo( $('body') );
setTimeout(function(){
    $c.addClass("dropped");}
,0)
```

The setTimeout adds that 'disconnect' between the action of adding it to the dom, and then changing the class (again, someone with more JS knowledge will have to chime in with the proper technical explanation as to why that works).

Comment: I'm using Firefox last version and you must set a delay of at least 6ms if you want it to work

Comment: @Oliboy50 huh. Interesting. Chrome seems fine with 0. If the delay is an issue, that could be a problem, but if not maybe even a 10th of a second would be a safer bet.

Comment: Hmm...I forked it here with the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/53xZ3/ and it seems to work fine with 0 on Firefox, Chrome and Safari on my MacBook. I wonder if this isn't so much a browser issue as a system issue. Hoping someone that understands the technical details of this issue can chime in.

Comment: hm yep your jsfiddle link really doesn't work for me on my Firefox 27.0.1 / Windows 8... but it does work on chrome

Comment: Hmm...seems ok on Firefox 27/Windows 7. I guess Windows 8 is to blame. :)

Comment: I think it's because when you have actions that cause reflow in the same function, the browser tries to render all of it simultaneously so the recently appended element isn't 100% finished establishing the things it needs to handle the animations when the class is applied. Placing the class change in the setTimeout puts it out of that scope and won't fire the timeout function until the enclosing function's actions have been completed.